# App memory size unexpectedly growth

Tags: android

I have an app, which is doing some basic operations like: download files, install files, query the phone, Using threads, HttpClient connections, etc.. (nothing too complicated).

it's also running a perm service inside(kind of Listener)

The wierd thing is: when I first intall it on my device, it's size in the memory is around 150 kb. but after a while (could be couple of days of activity), the size is growing unexpectedly, last time I check it got to 664KB.

What could be the reason? is this memory measure is realiable ? 
what should I check or how sould I solve it in order to keep it small while it's extracted in the memory?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually due to fragmentation of the heap, there are plenty of resources to research upon for regular Java VM's, you will have to check the Dalvik documentation for tools to assist with Android.

- [How fragmented is my Java heap?](http://blogs.oracle.com/jrockit/2008/09/repost_how_fragmented_is_my_ja.html)
- [Tips and tricks for dealing with a fragmented Java](http://blogs.oracle.com/jrockit/2008/09/repost_tips_and_tricks_for_dealing_with_a_fragmented_java_heap.html)
- [Dalvik heap fragmentation and recovery](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/android-platform@googlegroups.com/2009-03/msg00277.html)

Comment: Another weird thing, is that I cant "clear" the memory inside the application manager of this specific app? any idea why? maybe I need to enable it somehow?